# Unidentified Integrated Circuit - NEC 24 Prong

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

Today I was taking apart an old typewriter and I have this IC that was in a socket. I took it out and started searching online to see what this IC does. I spent 20 minutes and nothing showed up about it. It is a

```
 NEC 833IE9
 D2364EC 071.
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 3):

The question has insufficient information for a definitive answer, a photo would help.

Going by the description of it being a 24-pin device, and that it was socketed (which implies DIP, and also suggests replacement being a maintenance option), it could be [this NEC ROM device](http://doc.chipfind.ru/pdf/nec/d2364.pdf): **nMOS μPD2364**, 64 kilobit, 5 Volt TTL ROM, programmed at fabrication by the manufacturer.

Answer (score 2):

A little more info might be helpful. **What package is it in? What does it seem to be doing in the circuit?** Without really any more detail my first guess would be [this part](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/125068/NEC/UPD2364E-1.html).

In other words I think it's a ROM (read only memory) chip. I can't find anywhere selling them so they probably don't manufacture them anymore. (It is a old typewriter after all.) Is it near a `micro` or an `fpga` or something? That might help us figure out the mystery.